# Azure IOT central command/NodeRed

Tags: azure, iot, node-red, azure-iot-central

I'm currently exploring Azure IoT Central and have set up a device within it. Alongside this, I have an MQTT broker running via Node-RED on a Multitech gateway. My objective is to send commands from IoT Central to the MQTT broker, which should trigger my devices to respond with a 'true' or 'false' state.

My question is whether there is a method to transmit commands directly from IoT Central to the MQTT broker. I am relatively new to Azure and am unsure if I require an additional Azure service to facilitate this communication or if IoT Central provides a way to connect directly to the MQTT broker.

Any advice on how to configure this, especially if there are direct options without intermediary services, would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your support.[image]

Comment: You said send commands from IoT Central to the MQTT broker. transmit commands directly from IoT Central to the MQTT broker. what are commands? which mqtt broker are you using? add azure tag to your question also

Comment: commands are as u you see in the picture , i want to send True or FALSE TO THE BROKER ? my MQTT broker running on a multitech (node red) i have already three sensors  connected to my IOT central and they send data , and also the Dry Connect Lorawan device is already connected and waiting for commands , thank you in advance

Comment: i just wanna  send True or False to an MQTT broker ,is that possible @Sampath?

Comment: In the case, where your MQTT Broker (as a device) is connected to the Azure IoT Central App, just subscribe on the topic _$iothub/methods/POST/#_, see more details in the following document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub#respond-to-a-direct-method

Comment: @Brell we send true or false in message formate to MQTT broker

Comment: thanks guys my problem was the topic , it was wrong now when i change it to  $iothub/methods/POST/# it works  ,thank you so much

Comment: OK, I am going to put it as an answer for helping others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case, where your MQTT Broker (as a device) is connected to the Azure IoT Central App, just subscribe on the topic

```
$iothub/methods/POST/#
```

see more details in the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub#respond-to-a-direct-method)